# Front Facing Camera does not Auto Focus or Manually Focus

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-camera

**Current Behaviour**

I'm using [`react-native-camera`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) with iPads/iPhones and I use the front-facing camera to scan barcodes (Code39, Code128, QR, etc..) However when using the front-facing camera, it does not focus on the barcode or anything I put mildly close to the camera. The rear camera works absolutely perfectly however the front camera does not.

I have not been able to test android as I'm not building for android purely just iOS. I can't seem to find any information on getting the front camera to focus.

If I was to stand in the background, hold up my Code39 close to the camera but leave a small gap at the bottom, it would not try focus on the card however stay focused on me in the background.

I've also raised an [issue here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2231) on their GitHub page, but came here to see if anyone has ran in to this before, has a work around etc.

**Expected Behaviour**

I expect the camera to see the code is taking up a lot more of the screen than I am, focus on it, read the code and proceed to run the code `onBarCodeRead`

**What have I tried to fix it?**

- Disable the `autoFocus` as this was a fix for Android, no luck here.
- Manually set the `focusDepth`.
- Manually set `autoFocusPointOfInterest` to center of screen.
- Change the `zoom` to 0.2 and slowly increase to the point of where it starts to look silly.
- Set `onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected` to just console.log something as this was another fix for android.
- Update `react-native-camera@2.6.0`
- Update to master branch at `react-native-camera@git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git`

**How can I recreate it?**

- Create new react-native project
- `yarn add react-native-camera` / `npm install react-native-camera --save`
- set `type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}` to use the front camera.
- set `autoFocus={RNCamera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}` (It's on by default anyway, this just ensures it.
- set `onBarCodeRead={() => alert('barcode found')}`
- Try to scan a Code39 / Code128 - [(creatable here)](http://online-barcode-generator.net/)
- Try to scan it and you'll find the camera will not focus on it however stay focused on the background. This is also true if you cover the camera with your finger, when you pull your finger away you expect the camera to be out of focus to the background and try and re-focus. This is not the case, it will stay focused at a medium / long distance.

**Software Used & Versions**

- iOS: 12.1.4
- react-native-camera: ^2.1.1 / 2.6.0
- react-native: 0.57.7
- react: 16.6.1

**Code**

I render the camera in a [`react-native-modal`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) and I've put my code below.

```
<RNCamera 
  style={styles.camera}
  type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
  flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
  autoFocus={RNCamera.Constants.AutoFocus.on}
  captureAudio={false}
  onBarCodeRead={(barcode) => {
    if (this.state.isModalVisible) {
      this.setState({
        isModalVisible : false
      }, () => this.captureQR(barcode.data));
    }
}}>
```

**Relevant Package Code**

I found some code that seems relevant:

at `RNCamera.m` [method `updateFocusDepth`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/ios/RN/RNCamera.m#L275)

```
- (void)updateFocusDepth
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [self.videoCaptureDeviceInput device];
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (device == nil || self.autoFocus < 0 || device.focusMode != RNCameraAutoFocusOff || device.position == RNCameraTypeFront) {
        return;
    }

    if (![device respondsToSelector:@selector(isLockingFocusWithCustomLensPositionSupported)] || ![device isLockingFocusWithCustomLensPositionSupported]) {
        RCTLogWarn(@"%s: Setting focusDepth isn't supported for this camera device", __func__);
        return;
    }

    if (![device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
        if (error) {
            RCTLogError(@"%s: %@", __func__, error);
        }
        return;
    }

    __weak __typeof__(device) weakDevice = device;
    [device setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition:self.focusDepth completionHandler:^(CMTime syncTime) {
        [weakDevice unlockForConfiguration];
    }];
}
```

More specifically just this section here:

If `device.position == RNCameraTypeFront` it will just return providing it doesn't meet any of the other criteria.

```
    if (device == nil || self.autoFocus < 0 || device.focusMode != RNCameraAutoFocusOff || device.position == RNCameraTypeFront) {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IOS has [three `Focus Modes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2#Focus_Modes). You need to use `AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus`

> [AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturefocusmode/avcapturefocusmodecontinuousautofocus): The camera continuously autofocuses as needed.
>
> **You use the [isFocusModeSupported](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1390215-isfocusmodesupported): method to determine whether a device supports a given `focus mode`**, then set the mode using the focusMode property.

`react-native-camera` will change the focus in two different scenarios (you can set a breakpoint with `xcode` on this lines):

1. [`focusWithMode`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/960c5b1c1687742bcadd570f676e2689339e48b0/ios/RCT/RCTCameraManager.m#L1054) method will set the focus only if your frontcamera supports `isFocusPointOfInterestSupported` and `AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus`

The method will change the focus mode `[device setFocusMode:focusMode];` to `AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus` only if the following condition is returns `true`

```
[device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported] && [device isFocusModeSupported:focusMode]
```

If the condition returns `false`, there is no `autofocus`, **but** the picture may [be focused on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17226418/7295772) ExposureMode [`[device setExposureMode:exposureMode];`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/960c5b1c1687742bcadd570f676e2689339e48b0/ios/RCT/RCTCameraManager.m#L1059)

2. [`updateAutoFocusPointOfInterest`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/1b9fb63e56368f90be2b94e32815e2837b53da41/ios/RN/RNCamera.m#L240) changes the focus when the user taps on the screen, based on the `x, y` coordinates of his touch.

As there are several posts ([post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17226418/7295772), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18621765/7295772), [post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17226418/7295772), [post 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730338/7295772)) on stackoverflow stating that different iphone versions do not support all type of autofocus with the frontcamera, I suggest you to **set breakpoints** on those line of codes and check the value of [`isFocusModeSupported`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1390215-isfocusmodesupported) and [`isFocusPointOfInterestSupported`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1390436-isfocuspointofinterestsupported)

Comment: Disabling autoFocus would not allow me to set the focusDepth unfortunately. So what you're saying is that it is not possible with the front camera?

Comment: @swonder I posted my message for mistake ... I was not finished editing. This are the information I collected. I believe that you need to continue reading the react-native-camera `ios` sourcecode to understand how they are implement the `focusDepth`. They are using the [iphone api which here documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2#Focus_Modes)

Comment: @swonder I updated my solution. I found the code responsible for setting the focus on ios and I believe it is not executing as your frontcamera device may not support some functionalities required from `react-native-camera`. Please read my answer and follow my instructions to troubleshoot, then notify me with the result. Thanks